# Reason ${f_2}:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N},{f_2}\left( x \right) = 2x^2 -1$ is not Surjective

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand surjective functions.

I came across this explanation for why

${f_2}:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N},{f_2}\left( x \right) = 2x^2 -1$

is not surjective:

${y = f\left( x \right) = 2{x^2} – 1,}\;\; \Rightarrow {2{x^2} = y + 1,}\;\; \Rightarrow {{x^2} = \frac{{y + 1}}{2},}\;\; \Rightarrow {x = \sqrt {\frac{{y + 1}}{2}} .}$

Let, for example, $y = 5$. Then

$x = \sqrt {\frac{{5 + 1}}{2}} = \sqrt 3$.

That's fine, but I wonder if there is a simpler explanation:

I believe the range of $2x^2 - 1$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is $[-1, +\infty)$. By the definition I've read that the range must equal the codomain, the function is not surjective simply by this not being the case.

Am I missing something, or are both explanations correct please?

Comment: The idea of range is tied to the domain of the function. When you say the range is $[-1, \infty)$ (as an interval), then it is incorrect because $\Bbb{N}$ is a discrete set and for the given function the output will also be a discrete set (and not an interval). Finding an element in the co-domain which cannot be an output for the function is the simplest way to show that $f_2$ is not surjective.

Comment: What is a surjective function - I mean the definition? If you apply any reasonable definition here, it would mean that $f_2(x)$ covers every natural number as $x$ covers every natural number. Now there are various ways to show this is false quite simply, without going outside the natural numbers at all.

Comment: Each element of the codomain must be an image of (at least) one element of the domain.  Now $2$ is in the codomain and the bets are very low that $2$ is an image of an domain's element.

Comment: @AnuragA Are you saying that I can not use  [−1,∞) to express a range of integers, if the context makes it clear - that this notation is for real numbers only?

Comment: People have been very helpful in providing their own explanations as to why the function is not surjective, but I was hoping for feedback on my own attempt - is my explanation essentially correct? There are two parts to this - is what I say correct, and more generally, is a difference between range and codomain sufficient to disprove surjectivity? (This is the basis of my attempted explanation.)

Comment: @RobinAndrews There are a few issues here. For example, some folks have $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ and some don't. Suppose you say $0 \in \Bbb{N}$, then your function is NOT even well-defined. The reason being $f(0)=-1$ and $-1 \not\in \Bbb{N}$. In which case any discussion of ontoness is moot. Suppose you say $\Bbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4, \ldots\}$, then your claim that the range of $f$ is not equal to the co-domain ($\Bbb{N}$) needs to be justified. Now you cannot say that the range starts from $-1$. So how does one show that the range $\neq \Bbb{N}$ ? Well the simplest way is what I said in my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

As $2x^2-1$ is odd for any natural number $x$ no even number is in the image of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple explanation is that $f_2$ is strictly increasing as

$$f_2(n+1) - f_2(n) = 4n+1 \gt 0.$$

And as $f_2(2) = 3$ and $f_2(3)=17$, the integers $4, 5, \dots, 16$ can't belong to the range of $f_2$.